# Установка .net как зависимого компонента через Wix

Tags: .net, установка, wix

Приветствую! Я использую `wix` в качестве установщика `.net` приложения. Проект для установки проекта уже написан. Но нужно включить туда `.net framework 4`. Нашел способ решения через `bootstrapper` и `bundle`, но в этом случае пропадают диалоги при установки проекта (такие как выбор компонентов и указание портов для приложения). Можно ли обойти проблему, чтобы появлялись диалоги? Или как-то можно добавить установку `.net` в само приложение? Вообще идеально было бы, чтобы было 2 файла, 1й - это мой установочный пакет setup.msi из папки `..\` а 2й - это `framework_x64_x86.msi` из папки `..\packages\` и чтобы при запуске `setup.msi` устанавливался framework по выбору пользователя.

```
UPD
```

Нашел вариант, установить свойство  `DisplayInternalUI="yes"`. Если установить ключ, будет виден диалог проекта `setup.msi`. Теперь вопрос нужно задать `installCondition` для установки фреймворка в этот код:

```
<Fragment>
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                         Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\Full"
                         Value="Version"
                         Variable="NetFx4FullVersion"/>
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                         Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\Full"
                         Value="Version"
                         Variable="NetFx4x64FullVersion"
                         Win64="yes"/>
    <PackageGroup Id="NetFx4Full">
      <ExePackage Id="NetFx4Full"
                  DisplayName="Net Faramework 4.0"
                  Cache="yes"
                  Compressed="no"
                  PerMachine="yes"
                  Permanent="yes"
                  Protocol="netfx4"
                  Vital="yes"
                  SourceFile=".\packages\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
                  InstallCommand="/norestart" 
                  InstallCondition="Framework=&quot;Install&quot;"
                  DetectCondition="NetFx4FullVersion and (NOT VersionNT64 or NetFx4x64FullVersion)">
      </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>

    <Property Id="Framework" Value="NotInstall"></Property>
  </Fragment>
```

Решил делать через свойство и диалоги. Но как для проекта bootstrap можно задать диалог, что-то вроде `<UIRef Id="ChooseFrameworkDialog"/>`?

Answer (score 0):

В версии wix 3.6 нет возможности добавлять пользовательские окна в Bootstrap. Возможно такая возможность появиться в следующих версия Wix